# Simple SQL, Setting default value for multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql, null

So I'm doing homework for a class and I have been stuck on this problem for days, apparently I'm not as good at google as I need to be.

Here it is:
"Change the StoreReps table so that NULL values can’t be entered in the first and last 
name columns."

My Code (does not work):

```
    Alter Table StoreRep Modify lastname Not Null, Modify firstname Not Null;
```

My Code (does work but I need to be able to change both columns at the same time):

```
    Alter Table StoreRep Modify lastname Not Null;
```

Comment: Please add appropriate tags for SQL dialect you are using. From syntax I assume your RDMS is Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alter Table StoreRep Modify (lastname Not Null, firstname Not Null);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I am using Oracle for my class. I thought I tried this, but apparently I was missing the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you also need to specify the type:

```
alter table StoreRep
modify firstname varchar(50) not null,
modify lastname varchar(50) not null;
```

[See this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22d5b).

Comment: That all depends on dialect. Ravi Thapliyal's answer is good for Oracle, yours for MySql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query which can alter default value for multiple columns using single run:

```sql
     ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`  CHANGE `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL 
     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` 
     DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `post_modified` 
    `post_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE 
    `post_modified_gmt` `post_modified_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 
     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```